# Wordpress - Contact form 7 not sending mails to domain emails

Tags: wordpress, email, sendmail, contact-form-7

I'm trying to receive contact form 7 mails on my domain email but I don't get any but when I receive the emails on my personal free account (e.g. myemail@gmail.com) it works just fine.

[image]

Comment: You may need to use an [SMTP plugin for this](https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-set-up-wp-mail-smtp-with-any-host-ultimate-guide/). My guess is because WP is sending the email from what *appears* to be your domain to your domain, it's being seen as spam or not being delivered at all (as it is in your case).

Comment: I tried an email in a different domain and it's still not working.

Comment: If it works with you gmail address, it's still most likely a mail delivery issue with emails coming from a domain that appears to be a spoof domain. I would check into adding a SPF record to your DNS.